# Access Control Allow Origin in JSP

Tags: jquery, api, jsp

There are a lot of answers for resolving this issue but none of them seems to be working for me.

I want to get data from the Food2Fork API. Below is my jQuery code,

```
$.getJSON('http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=MYAPIKEY&q=shredded%20chicken',
                    function (data) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                );
```

Now I'm using a simple MVC architecture where I have a controller from which I'm accessing the JSP page by writing the below line,

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

The `home.jsp` is the page which has the above jQuery code. The controller i.e the Servlet file have the below line to allow access from other domain,

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Even after writing the above line in my controller I'm getting "No Access-Allow-Origin is present in the header". Any suggestions for this?

**PS:** I'm running this on localhost

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setHeader` instead of `addHeader`

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```